# uploading merge commit to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I am new to git and repo. I have made some changes to local repo and I want to upload those all changes on Gerrit for review. I want upload a merge commit instead of uploading individual commits.Can someone help me, I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Why do you want a merge commit? Depending on what you want to accomplish there are different ways of addressing it.

Answer (score 1):

You know that you will end up with a change request for every single commit? Every single one has to be submitted to the repo by a human.

So if this is not what you want, you should rebase and merge some commits together.

If you really want to upload all commits including the merge commit, you need the [Push Merge Commmits](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_merge) permission.